# UITableView cell redraw causes text to overlap

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I do following in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
LibraryCell *cell = (LibraryCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell != nil) {
    [cellIdentifier release];
    [self setItems:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
cell = [[[LibraryCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
[self setItems:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;
```

`[self setItems:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` changes only some UILabel's value inside the corresponding cell.

So now when I edit UITableView and delete let say the first row, the UILabel's value is no redrawn completly, i.e. the old value remains and new value is drawn overlapping the old one.
Why this happens and how to fix it ?

Comment: Please accept an answer if you think you have found what your problem is and can go on solving it with the information found here.

Comment: Actually the problem is not solved ! I want the answer for the question, i.e. why the cells are not fully redrawn. When I delete the fist row, the second row's text is displayed with the first one.

Comment: When you delete your cells, have you also delete the contents in your data source??

Comment: Post your updated code after implementing the suggestions given by the other answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I figured out ! The problem was coming from `setItems:forIndextPath` method.
It was creating UILabel locally and releasing it. So every time it was drawn over the last text text. Making the UILable instance variable solved the issue.

PS. The code originally was not written by me, I'm just fixing it :)

Comment: Glad you found it - might have been faster had you posted the remaining code, too :-)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you misunderstood the cell identifier concept.
It is only used to distinguish what you might call "stamps", used to print a cell's appearance on the screen. So you would most probably only need a single cell identifier.

It helps the system to cache instances of the "stamps". When `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called, you only have to pick which kind of stamp you want to use. If you created an instance of the correct one before (i. e. you get one back when asking for it using the cell identifier string), you only need to change the label texts etc. and then return it. In real life this might be likened to one of those date stamps where you can change the date by turning the little knobs on the stamp. This is what you would do by assigning a new text to the label contained in the cell.

You instead seem to be creating a stamp for each index in your model by concatenating the string value, effectively creating as many instances as there are rows in your model. Apart from being unnecessary it might also cause memory pressure and stuttering, because it counteracts all sorts of optimizations the UITableView has.

I recommend you read up on Apple's documentation or see iTunes U ([here](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=480479762))
 for the Stanford courses on iOS development. It gets explained very clearly there.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, You should use the same name for your cellIdentifier

Please refer to the `UITableView Class reference`
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

If you cannot get a reusable cell, then create it. After that update your cell.
The code should be like this

```
LibraryCell *cell = (LibraryCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)  {
    //  create a new cell
    ...
}

//  Update cell
...

return cell;
```

Comment: If I get the reusable cell I don't create it at all ! A new cell is created if reusable identifier returns nil.
Also why should I use the same identifier for all cells ? There is nothing about this in documentations, so far I've managed o see.

Comment: Daniel has explained it, take a look to it.
When you call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, the system will find the cell with cellIdentifier as your provided that is not in use (out of the view when you scroll). It you provide a different name, then each time you create a new cell, it will use up the memory if your table contains lot of data

Comment: Yeah I agree, I might use the same identifier in my case, but guys you don't focus on my question. The question is why the cell is not fully redrawn ? Although I've changed the code to use the same identifier for all cells but sill I get the cell with overlapped texts.

Comment: Can you post your updated code? and your setItems:forIndextPath

Comment: And please include the LibraryCell, too.

Comment: Thanks guys to all of you, for help ! I've got my problem solved ! The problem was that setItem created UILabel locally and released it each time, really newbie code (Originally written not by me ! please don't blame me :) ) +1 each of your from me, for help and tip to have a look in d*** setItem method ! Thanks !